# python + mysql Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'

Tags: python, mysql

I was trying to connect the mysql with python.

```
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect()
```

Uptill this point everything was fine. But after this when I started specifying the attributes of the connect command, using the code bellow

```
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",  #specifies the host computer(in this case this computer only)
    user = "root",   #specifies the user
    passwd = "<my password was here>"
    )
```

this error came up on running the code,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Co-valent Cyclist/Desktop/Python + MySQL/test 1.py", line 6, in <module>
    passwd = "co_valent_bonds"
  File "C:\Users\Co-valent Cyclist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 177, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Co-valent Cyclist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 104, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Co-valent Cyclist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 785, in connect
    self._post_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Co-valent Cyclist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 757, in _post_connection
    self.set_charset_collation(self._charset_id)
  File "C:\Users\Co-valent Cyclist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 716, in set_charset_collation
    charset_name, collation_name))
  File "C:\Users\Co-valent Cyclist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 970, in _execute_query
    self.cmd_query(query)
  File "C:\Users\Co-valent Cyclist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 590, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Users\Co-valent Cyclist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 478, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1115 (42000): Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'
```

how do I rectify this? Please help me out. Thanks!!

Comment: `passwd = r"co_valent_bonds"`

Comment: Hi, I tried this out but it is still not working and the same error is showing up. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Use charset="utf8" while creating the connection object .

If your characters actually use the superset utf8mb4 then this may cause problems, but if not, then this should work!

```
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",  #specifies the host computer(in this case this computer only)
    user = "root",   #specifies the user
    passwd = "<my password was here>",
    charset = "utf8"
    )
```